# Share ownership of Picasa web album

Tags: picasa-web-albums

I would like to share an album of photos with upload privileges among many people.  I can do this now by following the instructions on [this page](http://blogger-hints-and-tips.blogspot.com/2013/10/let-another-person-add-photos-to-your-picasa-web-albums.html).

Unfortunately recipients of the sharing don't have the album listed in the "My Photos" tab of Picasaweb, they seem to need to keep track of the link that I send to them.  Is there any way to maintain visibility of the album when they go to picasaweb.google.com?